# Is there a solution for Missing required parameters for [Route:....?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, laravel-route

Could someone please help me with this error? I have been struggling for days now.
[image]

> Missing required parameters for [Route: helper.update] [URI: helper/{id}]. (View: D:\Training\LaravelProjects\helps\resources\views\helper\edit.blade.php)

I have followed the documentation and still i can't figure out what is wrong. This is my code.

**Web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'helper'], function (){
 Route::get('/create', [
    'uses' => 'HelperController@create',
    'as' => 'helper.create'
 ]);

 Route::get('/{id}/edit', [
    'uses' => 'HelperController@edit',
    'as' => 'helper.edit'
 ]);

 Route::get('/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'HelperController@show',
    'as' => 'helper.show'
 ]);

 Route::post('/', [
    'uses' => 'HelperController@store',
    'as' => 'helper.store'
 ]);

 Route::put('/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'HelperController@update',
    'as' => 'helper.update'
 ]);

 Route::delete('/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'HelperController@destroy',
    'as' => 'helper.destroy'
 ]);
});
```

**HelperController.php**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $helper = Helper::find($id);
    return view('helper.edit', compact('helper'));
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<tbody>
                @foreach($helpers as $helper)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $helper->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $helper->email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $helper->telephone }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $helper->city }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $helper->district }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $helper->province }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $helper->category }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ route('helper.edit', $helper->id) }}" class="edit">
                            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" title="Edit" style="font-size: 16px"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal" data-widget="">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash" title="Delete" style="font-size: 16px"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

All I want is to open the **edit.blade.php** file once I click edit link. The delete part is incomplete and please ignore that.
Also, the id is being passed as a parameter but stil says it's missing. [image]

Comment: The error is in `edit.blade.php` view not in `index.blade.php` and it's about the `update` route not the `edit` route

Comment: the problem is in your edit page. not in the index page. share the edit page form action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `resources\views\helper\edit.blade.php` make sure to pass the helper id to the update post/put html form

```html
{{ route('helper.update', $helper->id) }}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, that has been done. But all i want is to open the edit.blade.php by passing in a parameter, which is what i am struggling with.

Comment: i don't understand why the id has to be passed there since I am not working on the submitting of the form to update.

Comment: Because the `route` function tried to compile a proper URL and reads what you have in `routes/web.php` and will throw an error when it fails to do so

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar problem with my project, **the problem here is your ID**. Those missing parameters are the IDs Which Can Not Be fetched by Laravel because it has a null value.

In PHPMyAdmin,

edit your SQL file and delete the table id responsible for storing information of the particular action that triggered the error.  Then add one column at the beginning of the table. set name to id, set length/value to 11, set type to integer (INT) then click on the box next to NULL and set the value to PRIMARY. wait for a popup and click OK. After that, tick the box under auto increment. save your table and now refresh and notice each column now has an id with different values. And Not Null. go back to Ur application and resubmit your request, it should work perfectly.

Comment: You should not include your email and website in your answers. You can reserve that for your personal profile if you so wish...